# git -- reorderging commits in terms of revisions (snapshots) not diffs

Tags: git, commit, rebase, git-rewrite-history

Say I have commit A that introduced some code generalization (some extra lines (denoted as `+L1`)) and a new feature (some extra lines again (denoted as `+L2`)). After that I realized that it would have been better to be split into two commits introducing +L1 and +L2 separately, so I did cut -L2 lines and committed it as B. Now what I want is rearrange A and B as **code states, not diffs**. Reordering with rebase obviously produces conflicts because basically I try remove non-existing -L1 at first and then add +L1 +L2.

In other words, what I want to do:

1. checkout some commit, but stay at old HEAD.
2. Stage all necessary files.
3. Commit

These steps basically make possible to write history in terms of snaphots but not diffs.

The problem here is with step 1 -- I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git reset SHA`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) for this. The default `--mixed` mode will move your branch and `HEAD` to the specified commit, but leave your files as the currently are on disk. From there, you can `git add --patch` pieces of your files to create the commit you want, then repeat as necessary.

Eg. if your repository looks like:

```
- A - B - C  master
```

`git reset A` will move `master` back to `A`, but your files will not be modified - they'll still have all the changes you've made since `A`, even if you made more edits after committing `C`.

Take note of you current commit hash before you start (or use `git reflog`) in case something goes wrong and you want to start over. In that case, `git reset --hard SHA` will move your branch again and set all tracked files back to the way they were at `SHA`. The `--hard` option is one of the few dangerous moves that could throw out uncommitted changes, but as long as at some point your code has been committed, you can always get back to it.